# I don't understand what is the question asking?

Tags: derivatives

> The limit below represents a derivative $f'(a)$. Find $f(x)$ and $a$. $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(4+h)^3-64}h$$

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative of a function $f$ at $a$?

Comment: Write down the definition of $f'(a)$ and compare against the limit in the question.

Comment: Your expression is a complicated way of writing $48$. It is impossible to guess an $f$ and an $a$ from that such that $f'(a)=48$. For all purposes $f(x)=48x$ and $a=0$ would do.

Answer (score 2):

derivative of any f(x) at $x=a$ is given as $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
comparing with  $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(4+h)^3-64}{h}$$
 $$\implies f(a+h)=(4+h)^3, \ f(a)=64$$
by putting $a=4$, in $f(a+h)=(4+h)^3$

i get $f(4+h)=(4+h)^3\iff f(x)=x^3$

then putting $x=4$ in f(x) gives $f(4)=64=f(a)$ so $a=4$ hence
$$f(x)=x^3, a=4$$